# When a power failure results in a fsck, which runlevel is systemd loaded into - emergency mode or rescue?

Tags: linux, filesystems, systemd, runlevel

Can someone please tell me which runlevel systemd is running in when you're prompted for a filesystem check after a power loss? Is it emergency or rescue or does it depend? I have some systemd units that need to run if/when the system prompts for a filesystem check at boot. I'd rather not modify the minimal emergency.target shell to load the script if I don't need to so I was hoping that it was running in rescue mode.

Also, if anyone has a nifty way of temporarily breaking the filesystem so I can invoke the fsck prompt for testing, I'd greatly appreciate it. I've tried changing /etc/fstab, however that specifically boots into emergency mode.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually neither – it's part of the regular boot process.

For filesystems listed in /etc/fstab with the "check" flag set to non-zero, the corresponding .mount unit automatically gets a dependency on `systemd-fsck@<dev>.service`. When that service finishes, systemd continues with mounting the filesystem (starting the .mount unit). This is not a special state, but part of the regular job queue.

If the fsck service fails (e.g. some kind of manual repair is required), the .mount unit also fails and only *this* finally triggers a switch from the regular boot target into `emergency.target`.

As you can see, fsck is being run on *every* boot, and the only thing affected by power loss is how long it'll take. (Some filesystems have a "dirty" bit that is set on mount and cleared on umount; others detect the state based on unprocessed entries in the update journal.) To change this behavior, you'd have to change the `fsck.<fstype>` program or completely disable checking for that filesystem in fstab.

To start additional services before `systemd-fsck@<dev>` runs (which would happen on every boot, *before* it decides whether extended checking is needed) use the regular methods of extending a systemd unit.

Note that the *root* filesystem is a special case: in some distributions it is actually checked in the *initramfs* (early boot phase), while the main systemd process is not running yet. (Depending on distro, the initramfs may have its own systemd, or a different init entirely.) Again, `fsck` is always run, whether the poweroff was clean or not.